# Проблема в маршрутах Laravel?

Tags: laravel

```
    The GET method is not supported for this 
    route. Supported methods: POST.
    Выдает ошибку хотя у меня везде прописан 
    метод Post
       <form role= "form" method="post" 
     action="{{ url('auth/register') }}">
     и в роутах тоже  прописал 
     Route::post('auth/register', 
     'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
     e\Routing\AbstractRouteCollection .php :117
     
    throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException(

        $others,

        sprintf(

            'The %s method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: %s.',

            $method,

            implode(', ', $others)

        )
```

Comment: У вас всё правильно прописано. Выложите форму целиком, чтобы было больше информации.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel говорит Вам, что нельзя просто получить эту страницу методом GET (то есть перейдя на нее из строки браузера). Если Вам необходимо проверить работоспособность контроллера этой страницы, то можете воспользоваться программой postman - посылать запросы на страницу, смотреть ответы, как обрабатывает данные, какие заголовки и т п.